# R-return the name with the least number of occurences

Tags: r, count, min

I need to find the sector with the lowest frequency in my data frame. Using min gives the minimum number of occurrences, but I would like to obtain the corresponding sector name with the lowest number of occurrences...So in this case, I would like it to print "consumer staples". I keep getting the frequency and not the actual sector name. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

```
sector_count <- count(portfolio, "Sector")
sector_count
                  Sector freq
1 Consumer Discretionary    5
2       Consumer Staples    1
3            Health Care    2
4            Industrials    3
5 Information Technology    4

min(sector_count$freq)
[1] 1
```

Comment: `with(sector_count,Sector[which.min(freq)])`

Comment: `count` is not a base R function. It's standard practice on this site to include a line like `library(dplyr)` before using such functions in code here.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you, this worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
sector_count$Sector[which.min(sector_count$freq)]
```

The `which.min(sector_count$freq)` function selects the index or row where the minimum value is found. The sector_count$Sector vector is then subset to the corresponding value.